# Laravel - Highlighting roles which are already assigned to a user

Tags: laravel, checkbox, view, edit

On user\edit view I'm displaying all roles as checkboxes. I'd like to have roles which are already assigned to a user checked. All other fields in the form are filled in with details from the database already. I'm trying to work with Spatie's Laravel Permissions.

[Image of the view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIvOY.png)

```
@foreach ($roles as $role)
    <input type="checkbox" value="{{$role->id}}" name="{{$role->name}}" > {{$role->name}}</input>
@endforeach
```

I would like to use pure HTML. I read about eager loading but from what I understood it will give me only roles assigned to a user, not all of them.

I want to use `sychRoles()` function when I click update button.
I was hoping to build similar view to what Voyager uses: [example](https://docs.laravelvoyager.com/core-concepts/roles-and-permissions).

Comment: In your database is there a field in user table which contains the roleid or something like that?

Comment: No, sorry. It's done via pivot table.

Comment: Can you share the models? user model and role model.

Comment: Code here: https://codeshare.io/GLbNw6

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It will check if there is any logged in user. Then it will match the roles of that user with id from roles relationship.

```
    @foreach ($roles as $role)
        <input type="checkbox" value="{{$role->id}}" name="{{$role->name}}" 
        @if(auth()->check()) 
             @foreach(auth()->user()->roles as $userRole)
                 @if($userRole->id==$role->id) {{"checked"}}
                 @endif
             @endforeach
       @endif> {{$role->name}}</input>
    @endforeach
```

Comment: No changes unfortunately.

Comment: Yes, I just checked your new comment. Unfortunately getting data from pivot table is a bit tricky.

It would work if there was a roleid in users table.

Comment: Sorry for being late. I updated the code. Please try it now.

Comment: This ticks/checks the roles of the logged in user. It needs to check roles of the user that I'm currently editing.

Comment: In this case "auth()->user()" will get the logged in user. If you want to edit another user you need to pass that user from controller. You need to search in database to find the user you are editing and return it to the view. Then instead of "auth()->user()->roles" you should write something like "$current_user->roles".

Answer (score 0):

try below:

in controller:

```
$roles = $user->roles;
```

in blade file:

```
@foreach ($roles as $role)
    <input type="checkbox" value="{{$role->id}}" name="{{$role->name}}"> {{$role->name}}</input>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score -1):

**Here is controller code**

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $role = role::find($id);
    $permissions = Permission::all();
    return view('admin.role.edit',compact('role','permissions'));
}
```

**And in view**

```
<div>
    <label for="name">Assigned Permissions</label>
    @foreach ($permissions as $permission)
        @if ($permission->for == 'user')
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label><input type="checkbox" name='permission[]' value="{{ $permission->id }}"
                @foreach ($role->permissions as $give_role)
                    @if ($give_role->id == $permission->id)
                        checked
                    @endif
                @endforeach
                >{{ $permission->name }}</label>
            </div>
        @endif
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Comment: What is questions ?
Add appropriate tags.